# Find strings in files with regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a bunch of files, where template tags are used. I want to list all the different template tags used in all of the files.

This is my used bash script, which gives no match...

```
for f in EHS/*.html;  do
  value=`cat ${f}`;
  [[ $value =~ "({%.*?%})" ]]
  if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} ]]; then
    echo "Found: ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}";
  fi
done;
```

This is a snippet from one of the html files:

```
<p>
  The ordernumber is: {%OrderNumber%}<br>
  The partnumer is: {%PartNumber%}
</p>
```

So my goal is to just return all of the different tags used...

Comment: $value is just one big string containing all the html...

Comment: I think `grep -o "{%[^%]*%}"` would be more natural to get all the matches like that from the file. In Bash, it is combersome to extract multiple matches.

Comment: Seems to work :) Can you explain the difference with my regular expression?

Comment: Bash regex does not support lazy quantifiers, and when you quote the pattern after `=~` inside `[[...]]`, literal string matching is triggered, it is not regarded as a regex. You could use `if [[ $s =~ \{%[^%]*%} ]];` but you will find a single match only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The regex should be unquoted, but `{}` needs escaping, as their meaning is special.
2. bash doesn't support frugal quantifiers like `*?`.

It's easier to use grep:

```
grep -o '{%[^}]*%}'
```

The `-o` option only returns the matching parts, one per line.

Note that strings like `{%ab%cd}ef%}` aren't matched as there's no easy way how to prevent parts of multicharacter delimiters in standard grep. With pgrep, you can use

```
grep -o -P '{%.*?%}'
```

as you originally intended.